# stripping out <![if !mso]> by displaying in tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

Currently I'm using a very old version(2.8) of `tinymce` and now I'm trying to upgrade it to newest version(4). In that process I'm facing few troubles and the main one is displaying `<![if !mso]>` in html viewer which was hide on the older version,

I'm using this editor as my mailing editor, So basically I'm loading a responsive html mailing text into the editor. But it shows `<![if !mso]>` this code all over the html viewer which has not interpret as a comment.

[image]

code I used, (as per the [example](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/))

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
  image_advtab: true,
  relative_urls : false
 });
```

Anybody have any idea how should I hide this `<![if !mso]>` codes from the HTML viewer. Please note that this comments are extremely important, so I don't want remove them from the html code before loading to the editor. I just need to hide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core issue here is that `<![if !mso]>` is not a valid HTML tag so TinyMCE (as a HTML editor) is treating it like text.  You can teach TinyMCE to protect certain text in the editor by using the `protect` option in your TinyMCE configuration:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#protect

For example you could do this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: textarea,
    protect: [
      /\<!\[if !mso\]\>/g,   // Protect <![if !mso]>
      /\<!\[if !vml\]\>/g,   // Protect <![if !vml]>
      /\<!\[endif\]\>/g,     // Protect <![endif]>
      /<\?php[\s\S]*?\?>/g   // Protect <?php ?> code
    ]
});
```

Please note that MS Office docs put in a whole slew of these non-standard markup tags so to catch all of them you may need to add additional items to your `protect` configuration option.

Comment: it seems it completely remove the `<![if !mso]>`, is it ?

Comment: I don't want to completely remove that, just need to hide it from the editor, but actually it should be in the html code

Comment: It does not remove the code from editor - it simply protects it so the editor does not show the text in the UI.

Comment: Look at this example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pAfaab/1  The `<![if !mso]>` does not get removed from the HTML code.  You can confirm this by looking at Tools / Source Code after the editor loads.

Comment: @MichaelFromin, sir... I have a script like `<img src="<?php echo $img_link; ?>" />` but when i save and reopen the source code view, it convert my PHP code to `lt;&amp;`  or `&lt;!--mce:protected` ... I am using `protect: [ /\<\/?(if|endif)\>/g,  /\<xsl\:[^>]+\>/g,   /<\?php.*?\?>/g ,  /<\?php[\s\S]*?\?>/g,  /\"\<\?php[\s\S]*?\?\>\"/g  ] `